# How to save a POST jpeg to a server using PHP that isn't coming from a html form?

Tags: php, post, upload, jpeg

I have to save a jpeg that is sent to my server as a POST with this information:
"The image will be uploaded to the URL by using the POST method. The field "data_image" will contain the image/jpeg data and the "data_device_id" field will contain the device id of this device."

I provide the URL to my server's PHP script.

I don't think I can use this: $_FILES from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp as  it is not coming from a form therefore I have no "name" of the form. I searched all over but I can't figure out how to take this jpeg data and save it to a file on my server using a PHP script. I know how to use $_FILES from forms but this I'm stumped.

Comment: 1. [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/)
2. You should try elaborating more on the structure of the upload. In layman's terms: code please. That _POST information_ sounds a bit wrong, there is no sense in posting legit sentences (except when they are comments or forum posts).
3. Try looking at [IO streaming](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Comment: Is the "information" really the requirements?

Comment: All I know about the upload structure is what is told to me in that quoted text.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as if you just have to save image data to a file:

```
file_put_contents('yourFilename.jpg', $_POST['data_image']);
```

However, it's possible that `$_POST['data_image']` is containing more data, maybe as an array or in some other kind of data format (JSON, XML), You can find out by having a look at the data:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

You could also save this output to a file or have it sent to you by email if the data can only be sent from an external source.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the way. I tried `file_put_contents('yourFilename.txt', var_dump($_POST));`  The file was empty but I got return data of "array(1){["data_device_id"]=>string(9) "123456789"}

Comment: `<?php
file_put_contents('deviceid.txt', $_POST['data_device_id']);
?>` successfully retrieves the device id. But I get a 0 byte file with `file_put_contents('yourFilename.jpg', $_POST['data_image']);`

Comment: Obviously, as your `var_dump()` didn't show any `data_image` field. You might have to get in touch with however is providing you with your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can access [variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) that are sent to your PHP script using the `$_POST` array:

```
echo "Device ID: " . $_POST['data_device_id'];
```